# Testing Joomla extensions

Tags: component, development, bugs, bug-testing

After recently having started developing a Joomla component, the question of how to systematically test it for bugs has entered my head.

I already have some experience in using testing frameworks for other programming languages than PHP and JavaScript (e.g. JUnit for Java), but although I have already developed projects in vanilla PHP/JS, I have yet to acquaint myself with testing tools specifically designed for these two programming languages.

A quick internet research suggests that there is a ton of testing frameworks for both PHP and JavaScript. Before settling for any of them, I would like to know whether there are frameworks which are particularly suited for or even specifically aimed at testing Joomla components (or more generally Joomla extensions, i.e. components, modules, plugins, and even templates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**phpunit** is the current official tool: http://docs.joomla.org/Running_Automated_Tests_for_the_Joomla_CMS

You can download the main Joomla repo to review how to build test cases: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/tests/unit